# Passwordless SSH from particular clients

Tags: ssh

I have a three server machines running Ubuntu 12.04 Server (xxx.xxx.xx.{01..03}). My workstation is Windows 7.

1. When I use PuTTy to ssh into any of three machines from my Windows machine, it asks me for password in each case (logging in as root, each machine has the identical root password).
2. When I log into one of the machines and then ssh into one of the others, it does not ask me for the password.

My hunch is that this is because each of the machines is trusted by the others. Given that I did not configure the machines (in particular, I did not set up keypairs or add them to the trusted users list), how can I test this hypothesis? What should I be looking for?

Comment: You should consider disabling direct root logins through SSH, and force logins to an unprivileged account first and then use sudo or su. The root account is commonly the target of automated attacks; forcing the login to go through an unprivileged account (preferably with a different password) makes such an attack much more difficult.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Agree fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can connect from one server to another the systems know each ssh-key. If you can login from serverA to serverB without password as user root then look into /root/.ssh/authorized_keys* on serverB there will be an entry for serverA. In the same directory, /root/.ssh/, you will find the private keys to access the other two servers.